# Error: fwrite: 'stream' undeclared in C

Tags: stream, fwrite

I am in my first year programming, studying at a tertiary level. I have had a good search of your website and google for anything and everything on fwrite, fopen, types invloved, also alternate methods in the logic of my program and the answer is has not been forthcoming. I've been debugging this for quite a few hours already. I am writing a .BMP to a file and am getting the following error message on compile:

gcc -g -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -o test working.c -lm

working.c: In function ‘serveBMP’:

working.c:190:47: error: ‘outputFile’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    fwrite (&pixelColor, sizeof pixelColor, 1, outputFile);

**Here is all of the relevant code (I hope):**

```
void serveBMP (int iteation) {
   int countP = 0;
   int countF = 0;
   char pixelColor;

   //To only create the file and write the header once
   if (countF == 0) {
      FILE *outputFile;

      outputFile = fopen(BMP_FILE, "wb");
      assert ((outputFile!=NULL) && "Cannot open file");

      writeHeader(outputFile);
   }

   //Writes to BMP
   while (countP<BYTES_PER_PIXEL) {
      if (iteation < ITERATION_MAX) {
         pixelColor = WHITE;
      } else {
         pixelColor = BLACK;
      }
   countF++;
   countP++;
   fwrite (&pixelColor, sizeof pixelColor, 1, outputFile);
   }
}
```

I obviously I need the header and fopen outside the loop this function is called in, but now the stream is undeclared for some reason. Does anyone have a possible answer for this, or if need be a way around this. I have already spent quite a bit of time experimenting with creating the file in a different function and passing in the FILE *pointer with no success.

Thank you,
Ryan.

**Edit**

I now put FILE *output outside the if statement and still get the same error. 
Also I deleted a ' I thought was a typo after the ; on a line and am now getting errors. I've tried putting it back in many combinations. So confusing...

```
gcc -g -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -o test working.c -lm
working.c: In function ‘mapBMP’:
working.c:127:53: error: missing terminating ' character [-Werror]
          iteation = escapeSteps (displace, inputXY);'
                                                     ^
working.c:127:10: error: missing terminating ' character
          iteation = escapeSteps (displace, inputXY);'
          ^
working.c: In function ‘serveBMP’:
working.c:185:47: error: ‘outputFile’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    fwrite (&pixelColor, sizeof pixelColor, 1, outputFile);
                                           ^
```

Comment: My `c` is a little rusty, but it looks to me like you're declaring `outputFile` inside an `if` block and it's out of scope when you reach the `fwrite`  that's reporting the error.

Comment: I now put FILE *output outside the if statement and still get the same error. Also I deleted a ' I thought was a typo after the ; on a line and am now getting errors. I've tried putting it back in many combinations. So confusing...

Answer (score 0):

Put the declaration of `outputFile` outside the block starting with `if (countF == 0) { ...`:

```
//To only create the file and write the header once
FILE *outputFile;
if (countF == 0) { ... }
```